# Evaluating $\frac x y $, given $\frac{1}{x^{y+1}} = y$

Tags: proof-verification, exponential-function

> $$\dfrac{1}{x^{y+1}} = y$$
>
> Evaluate
>
> $$\dfrac x y $$

We know that

$$\dfrac{1}{x^{y+1}} = {x^{-(y+1)}}$$

Which yields

$$x^{-y-1} = y$$

Multiplying the both sides by $-1$

$$x^{y+1} = \dfrac 1 y$$

Multiplying the both sides by $x$

$$x^{xy+1} = \dfrac x y$$

Comment: Are these real numbers?

Comment: What should $\frac x y$ be evaluated in terms of?

Comment: $(x^{y+1})\cdot x = x^{y+2}$ not $x^{xy+1}$.  What you seem to have been thinking of might have been $(x^{y+1})^x$ but that would have simplified to $x^{(y+1)x}=x^{xy+x}$ not $x^{xy+1}$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner They are.

Comment: In any case, RushabhMehta brings up a very valid point.  Normally for problems like this, we try to express the answer in terms of the fewest variables (*or expressed in specific variables*).  $\frac{x}{y}$ and $x^{y+2}$ are both written in terms of two variables, so neither accomplishes the goal of reducing the number of variables.  Why should $x^{y+2}$ be a more desirable final answer than $\frac{x}{y}$ itself?  (*I know it is silly to give $\frac{x}{y}$ as an answer to the question of "express $\frac{x}{y}$" but it isn't "wrong" per se, and no more or less correct than $x^{y+2}$ is*)

Answer (score 0):

Your final step is not correct. $a\cdot a^b=a^1\cdot a^b = a^{1+b}$. Multiplying numbers with the same base is additive in the exponent, not multiplicative. So, $x\cdot x^{y+1} = x^1\cdot x^{y+1} = x^{1+y+1} = x^{y+2}$.

Putting this all together:

$$\dfrac{x}{y} = x^{y+2}$$

In terms of a single variable, you have

$x=\left(\dfrac{1}{y}\right)^{\tfrac{1}{y+1}}$

So, that gives you:

$$\dfrac{x}{y} = \left(\dfrac{1}{y}\right)^{\tfrac{y+2}{y+1}}$$